# Spring Webflux exchangeToMono() does not emit any items

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using below webflux version in my code.

```
    <!-- Spring Boot Web Starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version> 3.1.5 </version>
    </dependency>
```

I have a code that makes a call to a different microservice and if response is 2xx it does something , if its not 2xx it does something else.

```
public Mono<FooResponse> performAPICall(FooRequest request) {

String requestBody;
try {
  requestBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
  log.error("Unable to convert request to string");
  return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("objectMapper conversion failed"));
}

return webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
    .uri(ENDPOINT)
    .bodyValue(requestBody)
    .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
      log.info("Response status code:{}", clientResponse.statusCode()); // Logs 200 OK
      if (clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(FooResponse.class)
          .doOnSubscribe(sub -> log.info("Subscription Successful"))
          .doOnNext(body -> log.info("Received body: {}", body))
          .doOnSuccess(body -> log.info("FooResponse Mono completed"))
          .doOnError(ex -> log.error("Error processing FooResponse Mono", ex))
          .flatMap(resp -> {
              log.info("Success")
              return Mono.just(resp)
              }
         });

      } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class)
            .flatMap(resp -> {
              log.error("Error")
              return handle4xxError(resp); // Handles error and throws exeption
            });

      } else {
        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMap(resp -> {
                log.error("Error")
              return handle5xxError(resp); // Handles error and throws exeption
            })
      }
    });
```

}

I only see the below logs getting printed in the same order (Left to Right)

> "Response status code: 200 OK" ,
> "Subscription Successful" ,
> "FooResponse Mono completed"

I don't see any other logs , there are no failures. I am puzzled as to what is happening. Could anyone please explain this  behaviour?